# PrimeNG piechart not appearing in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, pie-chart

Hi im following the document on primeng's page.
i have already installed charts.js package using npm

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import {ChartModule} from 'primeng/chart';
@NgModule({ 
...
imports: [
...
ChartModule,
],
... })
```

**Piechart.component.html**

```
<h2>Members</h2>
<p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="data"></p-chart>
<p>piechart should appear here^^</p>
```

**Piechart.component.ts**

```
data: any;

constructor() {
    this.data = {
        labels: ['A','B','C'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ]
            }]    
        };
}
```

according to the documentation the piechart should appear but for some reason it does not appear and instead just leaves a gap??
[scrnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfLsm.png)

please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your `angular.json` file, if not already added:

```
"architect": {
 "build": {
  //..others
  "options: {
   "scripts": [
     "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
     //..others
     ],
     //..others
    }
  }
  //..others
 }
```

Comment: it is already added but it still does not appear